# Href no me funciona en el celular

Tags: php, html, href

los consulto porque me está pasando algo muy raro,

Hago un Href y en el Navegador de la PC me funciona muy bien, pero en el celular es como que no lo reconociera, me muestra las imagenes que no me permite interactuar con ella.
El Código es:

```
<div class="example2borra">
<ul class="nav">

<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $z; $i++)
{


if ($Estado=="s"){
?>  
<li><a class="fechasus" ><?php echo " $dato2[$i] Susp"; ?></a></li> 
<?php
}
else{
if ($Estado=="t"){

?>

<li><a class="fecha" href="resulresultados.php?idcar=<?php echo $Idcarrr[$i] ;?>&idi=<?php echo $user_language ;?>  " ><?php echo $dato2[$i] ; ?></a></li>



<?php
}

else {

?>

<li><a class="fechapend" ><?php echo $dato2[$i] ; ?></a></li>

<?php
}}
}

?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Y este mismo código me funciona en otras páginas

Comment: A este código expresado le está faltando justamente el href a los A

Comment: El unico href es este <li><a class="fecha" href="resulresul  los otros dos solo muestran una imagen

Answer (score 0):

No se cual habría sido el problema, pero no había manera de que funcione.

Se resolvió, cuando el mismo código lo escribí  en un archivo nuevo sin modificar nada.